# Type of pointer to member function without const/volatile/ref-qualifier

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Say I want to specialize a template on PMF types, I can do:

```
template<typename F>
struct Foo {};

template<typename R, typename T>
struct Foo<R T::*> {};
```

The `R T::*` part is also what `std::mem_fn` uses to avoid overloading on all combinations of qualifiers. (See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).) However, a drawback to this approach is we lose the type information about the parameters of this member function.

If instead we write:

```
template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (T::*)(Args...)> {};
```

We can know the exact parameter types (`Args...`), but this specialization cannot be matched against a `const` member function (or `volatile`/ref-qualified ones).

Is there a way to retain the parameter types while not needing to make specializations for all the qualified versions of the PMF?

Comment: Make use of a more general `function_traits`. To build such a thing, you can specialize the cases for function types (e.g., `int(double) const`) and then implement support for pointers to members using those.

Comment: @chris Can you give an example (or link to an example)?

Comment: @ZizhengTai : [CallableTraits](https://github.com/badair/callable_traits)

Comment: CallableTraits will help at runtime, perhaps, but not at compile time if I understand correctly.   Since your type doesn't specify that it's const, then you can't know at compile time  if the thing you actually passed is const or not.

Comment: It's only 12 combinations, quit being a whiner :)   If they share code, you can easily make them all point to common code and perhaps use a macro to shorten things up.

Comment: @xaxxon, It's 24, or 48 if you add C++17's changes to `noexcept`. Cv-qualifiers, ref-qualifiers, ellipses, and `noexcept` in all.

Comment: Something like this: https://godbolt.org/g/AMFrhi  combined with something like (http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/TypeTraits.h?view=markup) this to actually strip the const off (unlike the code I wrote) might work?

Comment: @xaxxon Reading the source code of Loki it seems Andrei is also using brute force to enumerate every possible combination :-)

Comment: @xaxxon : No aspect of CallableTraits functions at runtime; I'm not sure what would give you that impression.

Comment: @chris Ellipses? Do you mean varargs?

Comment: What is the use case here?  You can avoid specifying @const@ qualifications, etc. specializations by doing something like `decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<ARGS>()...))`, but that requires knowing the name of the function.